# Super() class's attributes not inherited?

Tags: python-3.x

It  seems the child class doesn't inherit the parent attributes, despite calling `super().__init__(args)`.
I read

[Python: subclass inherits super class attributes, but loses it's other attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100425/python-subclass-inherits-super-class-attributes-but-loses-its-other-attribute)

and

[Subclass is not inheriting the attributes of second Super Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231787/subclass-is-not-inheriting-the-attributes-of-second-super-class)

but I read the attributes should be inherited if called within `super().__init__()`

With the following code (3.10.1)

```
class interface(object):
    MEDIA = ('COPPER','FIBER')
    SPEED_COPPER = ('100', '1G', '2.5G', '5G', '10G')
    SPEED_FIBER =  ('10G', '25G', '40G', '100G')
    TYPE_L2 = ('ACCESS', 'TRUNK', 'HYBRID')
    
    def __init__(self, media = None, speed = None):
        self.media = media
        self.speed = speed
    
    def set_media(self):
        pass
    
    def is_copper(self):
        return self.media == 'COPPER'
    
    def is_fiber(self):
        return self.media == 'FIBER'

class copper_1G(interface):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(media = 'COPPER', speed = '1G')

class generic_mod(object):
    def __init__(self, max_slots):
        self.slots = []
        self.max_slots = max_slots
        self.set_interfaces()
    
    def set_interfaces(self):
        if len(self.slots) < self.max_slots:
            for slot in range(0,self.max_slots):
                self.slots.append(copper_1G)


class module48_2(generic_mod):
    MAX_SLOTS = 48
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.MAX_SLOTS)
        self.set_interfaces()

>>> ff=module48_2()

>>> ff.slots[0].media
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'copper_1G' has no attribute 'media'
>>> ff.slots[0].speed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'copper_1G' has no attribute 'speed'
```

the variable ff.slots[0] doesn't get the attributes media and speed of the parent class, though it gets the methods is_copper, is_fiber, etc etc...

Comment: Did you want an instance in slots? `self.slots.append(copper_1G())`

Comment: You're adding the `copper_1G` _type_ to the list, not an _instance_ of that type.

Comment: Ouch! Thanks to both!

Answer (score 0):

```
class generic_mod(object):
   ...
    def set_interfaces(self):
        if len(self.slots) < self.max_slots:
            for slot in range(0,self.max_slots):
                self.slots.append(copper_1G)
```

`self.slots.append(copper_1G)` -> `self.slots.append(copper_1G())`